# Clean Install of 14.04, but it waits and waits on shutdown, any idea why?

Tags: shutdown

I have put Ubuntu 14.04 on my old AMD64 HP NX6325. ** Internet NOT connected **
it all went very well.
It worked, one might say perfectly.
Looks good, sounds good, though it needs updates before it will play any mpegs.

but when it shuts down, it has the dots cycling away for more than 10 mins(got very bored).
Had to hold in the off button to end it.
tried starting, and NOT logging in, then choose Shutdown, does same thing.
My best guess would be its waiting for some Network thing.
any ideas what to kill/uninstall/fiddle with.
thanks for looking
Lol

Answer (score 0):

Once you click on shutdown press Ctrl-Alt-F6 and observe what happens.
To come back Press Ctrl-Alt-F7

Comment: Thanks, i tried that and it reveals  two messages that appear about 4 secs after shutdown sequence starts. They are Modem Manager messages. first one say something like could not aquire org.freedesktop ModemManager1, and second says ModemManager is shutdown. so i assume this has collapsed a thread and therefore the shutdown will never complete. so what next?

Comment: i guess now you go copy that part from syslog and ask new question. Or perhaps just switch off modem driver.